# How do I have 3 divs side by side with the rightmost one taking up the remaining width?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout where I have a small bar (not navbar), then below it, I have 3 divs floating left. How do I make the rightmost one occupy the rest of the width of the page?

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex` on the parent instead of floating the children, then set the one you want to occupy the rest of the space to use `flex-grow: 1`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.pancakes {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="pancakes">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would not recommend adding 'grow' in the class via markup - because, at any other breakpoint, you may NOT want it to grow. It should likely be a list - and you could target it with last-of-type or by class. Also - the shorthand for flex is a bit confusing for beginners when you don't explain what it does.

Comment: @sheriffderek OP didn't give context as to what's in the elements, so I used the generic `div` and not a list, which would only be semantic if the content is actually a list. They said they have 3 divs floating left. Seems more appropriate to use divs in the example than a list, but whatever, I'm not arguing with you. And you could enable `flex-grow` any number of ways. A class, `:nth-child` or whatever. If you wanted to change the behavior, you'd need to overwrite the CSS *some way*, so I don't see why not to use a class in the markup and use `:nth-` instead. 6 of 1, half dozen of another

Comment: @sheriffderek good call on `flex-grow` though, didn't realize I had written it with shorthand and referenced the actual property in the description.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your markup - I just used `<li>` because that would be my preference. Beyond that, I explained my point as well as I can. It's like adding a `float-left` class on something - that may not be floated left at some breakpoint.

Comment: @sheriffderek *"It should likely be a list"* what's that in reference to? Agreed, OP can call the class whatever they want, something more semantic would definitely be advised, but I don't know their code or context, it's just a simple example. But even if I used `.flex > div:last-child`, that could also unnecessarily target thing, so it wouldn't be perfect either. Fortunately it's just SO and the principles are what I'm trying to get across, not the class name they should use across their site. Like I might give something a class of `.red` in an answer...

Comment: @sheriffderek even though you should never use `.red` on something, or `.float-left` like you said, but I don't know their context so I don't know what would be proper/semantic. OP didn't provide any code so I just made something up. How about I call it `.pancakes` instead?

Comment: The context should alway involve the cleanest most maintainable code - is my standpoint. but relax. I also think pancakes would have been great. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek relax? everything's fine boss. thanks for your opinion. glad you like pancakes, but what if OP decides to change it to a waffle down the road? or oatmeal?!!?! maybe OP doesn't even eat breakfast! I think the solution is to implement a random class generator or use a css obfuscater. I'll sleep on it and get working on it in the morning.

Comment: I think that a random HTML generator would be best - and then we could build a stylesheet that just works for every scenario possible.

Comment: With declarative programming like this, there is going to be churn. Whether the markup changes - or the styles change - something is going to change that will require adjustments. I don't think there is a silver bullet - but keeping ALL of the styles in the stylesheet has served me well in recent years. It all depends on your team too. Some of my meetup friends really like being able to add classes to their markup - but they are also not fully in the mobile-first mindset yet.

Comment: @sheriffderek we could talk about this all day. I don't see the point over such a simplistic answer for a person who asked a question that probably shouldn't have even been answered since they didn't provide any code or ask the question properly. If they had included code, we could have just used their markup and there would be no need to back and forth. I'm not trying to teach anyone (OP) semantic CSS, nor am I making an argument for just making up random words in CSS, just answering a simple question simply. Yours and my question are not wrong. I don't see the point in being so meticulous.

Comment: @sheriffderek changed the class to pancakes. Hopefully you're OK with that and we can all move on.

Comment: For the record, I upvoted your answer, to begin with. I love you, Michael.

Comment: @sheriffderek LOL. This might have become the most interesting conversation I've had on SO.

Comment: and Rolando will likely never know.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is the way to go. Don't forget to use [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) with whatever build tool you use or to add the vendor prefixes by hand.

### Markup

```
<section class="things">
  <ul class="thing-list">
    <li class="thing">thing one</li>
    <li class="thing">thing two</li>
    <li class="thing">thing three</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

### Styles

```
.things {
  border: 1px solid red
}

.thing-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.thing-list .thing {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.thing-list .thing:last-of-type {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I also suggest you build a jsFiddle next time. As simple as possible to show the scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/26btxypb/

### Gnar

```
.thing-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}
.thing-list .thing:last-of-type {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}
```